# Trouble with Angular ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, azure-ad-msal

I have an app that I inherited from somebody that left our organization.
I’m having a problem with ngOnInit not working the way I think it should.
I’m still pretty new using Angular and Observables

I can see in the console when I navigate to the component it entering the ngOnInit method, what I don’t see is the console.info statement in the subscribe for the response being executed.
Once I’m in the component, I can refresh the page and then I can see the console.info statement in the subscribe.

My question is why don’t I see the console.info statement when I first navigate to the component?

Component ngOnInit() method

```
    ngOnInit(): void {

      console.info('Entering ngOnInit - Home Component');

      this.profile.getProfile().subscribe((resp) => {

          this.currentUser = this.local.getObject(StorageItems.UserProfile) as IMSALUserProfile;

          console.info('Current User: ', + JSON.stringify(this.currentUserInit));
      });
    }
```

This is what my service looks like, it’s a service that is fetching user profile information from Azure Active Directory using MSAL.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseService } from './base.service';
import { AuthError } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { LoggerService } from './logger.service';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { IMSALUserProfile } from '../../shared/interfaces/msaluserprofile';
import { SessionService } from './session.service';
import { StorageItems } from '../../shared/interfaces/enums/storage.model';
import { LocalStorageService } from './local-storage.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { IUserInit } from '../../shared/interfaces/userinit';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserProfileService extends BaseService {

  currentUser!: IMSALUserProfile;
  currentUserInit!: IUserInit;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, 
      private logger: LoggerService, 
      private session: SessionService,
      private local: LocalStorageService, 
      private userInit: UserService) {
    super();
  }

  public getProfile(): Observable<IMSALUserProfile> {

    let sessionUser = this.session.getItem(StorageItems.UserProfile);

    if (sessionUser.length !== 0) {
      this.currentUser = JSON.parse(this.session.getItem(StorageItems.UserProfile));
    }

    let profile!: IMSALUserProfile;

    if (this.currentUser) {
      
      profile = this.currentUser as IMSALUserProfile;
    } else {
      this.http.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me')
      .subscribe({
        next: (profile) => {
          profile = profile;

          this.local.setItem(StorageItems.UserProfile, profile);
          this.session.setItem(StorageItems.UserProfile, JSON.stringify(profile));

          this.currentUser = profile as IMSALUserProfile;
        },
        error: (err: AuthError) => {
          console.info('Authentication error');
        }
      })
    }

    this.local.setItem(StorageItems.UserProfile, profile);
    this.session.setItem(StorageItems.UserProfile, JSON.stringify(profile));

    return of(profile);
  }
}
```

Comment: `getProfile()` is a mess. I suggest you place a debugger there and go with it, there's probably an error there stopping the execution. you can comment everything and just `return of({})`. to be on the safe side, also comment that `this.currentUser = ...` on your component. you'll see that both your `console.info` statements will work. start uncommenting piece by piece and find the error. while at it, refactor the thing. asap.

Comment: Just to confirm, in the ngOnInit if I do a console.info on resp, for this line. this.profile.getProfile().subscribe((resp) => {

Shouldn't I see the response from the call to the profile service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning `of(profile)` when profile is just undefined. If `this.currentUser` doesn't exist, and the `else` block is executed, you're trying to set your return value asynchronously. Likely the function returns before the http.get can ever finish.

Rather than subscribing in the service, you probably want to return the http request and pipe it through some RxJS operators to do whatever logic you're currently doing in the subscribe inside the else block.

Comment: Conner, thanks for the guidance. It was indeed something in the service that wasn't working correctly. I have it working now.